# Override file in Gradle build dependency jar

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradlew

I would like to output a jar which internally contains my dependency jar but overrides a particular file in the dependency jar with my own. I am using gradle build. Can someone help me with this? The task which build jar for me:

    `jar {
     archiveName "JarName-${version}.jar"
      dependsOn configurations.runtime
      from {
       (configurations.runtime - configurations.provided).collect {
        it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
      }
    }
  }`

Answer (score 0):

Well I actually stopped duplicating the file by including the following strategy:
duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE

It seems like my changes becomes a part of the output jar before they are being overridden by the file in my dependency jar. So, restricting duplicacy helped in resolving the issue.